# Getting ssd, should i keep the ssd cache drive

Tags: storage, hard-drive, ssd

We are going to install sdd's as main hdd in all of our pc's.
However, some of them already have an ssd drive that is beeing used as a cache drive.

Should be keep this chace ssd?

It was my though that, currently io does the following:

```
cpu cache -> ram -> ssd cache -> hdd
```

But since the hdd will be an ssd as well, is it still benificial to keep the ssd cache? Or does this give extra overhead?

Comment: I don't understand???

Comment: @ewwhite you have set a ssd to be used as a cache drive, to speed things up a bit (like hybrid drives) but is it still usefull to use this if the actual hard drive is a ssd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not beneficial because they will be of a similar speed and writing things multiple times. (In fact bigger SSD drives are faster because they use flash in parallel)